# Django - ManyToManyField does not let me save, "This field is required" even though I select something

Tags: django

I have a formset like so:

```
class TransactionForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = kwargs.pop("user")
        except KeyError:
            user = None
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["date"].widget.attrs["class"] = "datepicker"

        if user is not None:
            self.fields["categories"].queryset = Category.objects.get_all(user)
            self.fields["account"].queryset = Account.objects.for_user(user)

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        exclude = [""]
TransactionFormSet = modelformset_factory(Transaction, form=TransactionForm, exclude=("",))
```

View:

```
def transaction_create_view(request, account_id=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = TransactionFormSet(request.POST)
        print(formset.errors)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                if form.is_valid and form.has_changed():
                    form.save()

    if account_id is not None:
        transactions = TransactionFormSet(queryset=Transaction.objects.for_account(account_id, request.user))
    else:
        transactions = TransactionFormSet(queryset=Transaction.objects.for_user(request.user))

    transactions.form = curry(TransactionForm, user=request.user)
    transactions.forms.insert(0, transactions.forms[-1])
    del transactions.forms[-1]    
    context = {"transactions":transactions,}
    return render(request, "transactions/transactions.html", context)
```

Model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    date = models.DateField()
    payee = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    outflow = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    inflow = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    cleared = models.BooleanField()

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

And template:

```
<form action="{% url 'transaction_create' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ transactions.management_form }}

    {% for form in transactions %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save transaction" />
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

I input information in the empty form it produces and click on the save button, but the formset is not valid and I get this when I print the errors:

```
[{'categories': ['This field is required.']}, {}]
```

The categories in the template are represented by a `<select>`, where I select a category (the background is colored). Apparently it is not set though and thus I can't save, why is that? How can I fix it?

EDIT:

I have no idea why but now it works.

I reset the database re-created some data to see if that fixes things, and it did, I didn't change anything in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you override the save() in TransactionForm, you have to call save_m2m() to save the m2m objects.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/